# XPath for expressions on same attributes connected by "or"

Tags: winapi, xpath

I need to write a xpath expression to satisfy the following requirement:
EventID with 4357 or EventID with 8473 or EventID with 3689 should be resulted.

I wrote it as follows:

```
"*[System/EventID = 4357 or EventID = 8473 or EventID = 3689]"
```

it results event id with 4357 only. It means it results only results that satisfies first expression. I don't have any idea about how to write this query. How to write such queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XPath 1.0, you can either do it this way :

```
*[System/EventID = 4357 or System/EventID = 8473 or System/EventID = 3689]
```

or this way :

```
*[System[EventID = 4357 or EventID = 8473 or EventID = 3689]]
```

Comment: It supports maximum 23 events